# Maximum torque conditions

Tags: motor, torque

Suppose the following machinery :

[image]

The induced torque is given by the following formula :

[image]

where K is a constant which depends on the motor construction. Bs is the constant (in magnitude and in direction) magnetic field. Bloop is the magnetic field of the loop when a current is flowing through the loop via the voltage induced on it when the loop is turning.

[image]

The formula shows that the torque is maximum when the angle between the magnetic field Bs and the magnetic field Bloop is equal to 90°. I know that the formula is correct but it is not so intuive to me : If I consider the loop wire as a magnet, as it produces a magnetic field, I should say that the highest torque is produced when the two magnets are aligned like shown below :

[image]

Why the torque is not maximum when the angle between Bloop and Bs is equal to 0 or 180° ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why would you expect torque from a symmetrical figure? Supposing the "magnetic lines of force" were force lines, how would the arrangement pictured, generate a torque? In what direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the force vector may be maximum with the two magnets repelling, but torque is defined as the [cross product](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Calculus-Based_Physics_(Schnick)/Volume_A%3A_Kinetics_Statics_and_Thermodynamics/21A%3A_Vectors_-_The_Cross_Product_and_Torque#:%7E:text=The%20relational%20operator%20is%20called,%E2%86%92r%C3%97%E2%86%92F) of the position vector from axis of rotation to application of force and the force vector.

\$\overlineτ =\overline r × \overline F\$

In your example, the torque is exactly zero, since the force is applied in line with the position vector. It's like trying to close a [door](https://www.marvin.com/blog/parts-of-a-door) by pushing on the edge, there can be plenty of force, but no net torque:

[image]

There's an implicit simplifying assumption that the field is uniform in the answer so maybe the peak torque is not quite at 90° but it won't be at 0° or 180°.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your example. And for the assumption that the field is uniform !

Answer (score 1):

Take two bar magnets and drill a hole in each. The holes should be half way along the bar magnets. Place the magnets on a piece of wood and nail them loosely in place. Loose enough so that they can be easily rotated. Make sure they are close enough to feel each others magnetic field.

You will find that when N and S are perfectly aligned there is an attractive force nut no movement. No movement means zero torque.

Now rotate one to 90 degrees and release it. A torque is present that spins it back so that N and S are aligned. Then there is no more torque

Comment: I see what you mean ;) I confused torque and force